# Rails worker optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, resque, worker

I have couple of worker running background job. The method in this workers are like ~100 lines. What are general practices in optimizing and moving code to different files in Rails for Workers.

Answer (score 0):

You just need do some new class and require in top of you worker.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use resque, but the problem here is what we load all environment with each worker, so worker natively are very slow. I think the good idea about this is to load only class what you really need.